# Bootstrap Multiple Class Conflict

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. I have this question coming up in my mind.
Since we can use multiple classes for a particular element, What happens if the two classes we use have the same attribute? I tried using something like this:

```
<div class = "pull-left pull-right">
    <p> Test </p>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class = "pull-right pull-left">
    <p> Test </p>
</div>
```

In both the cases my div was pulled left. How does bootstrap prioritize ?

Comment: Because pull-right and pull-left have same property float: and both have important. So if you need dom on left just add pull-left and if you need don on right just add pull-right. Why you need both class in same dom?

Comment: @PragneshKhalas that was just an example. more complex styles might have conflicting attributes like these. so which ones get prioritized. My question is conceptual. not specific to this example

Comment: css property priority based on last render in the css if both have same property. If you need to add specific style then it need to add that style in local page level(after refer the css) with !important so that style will be applicable in your page because page level style render after render the added css style.

Comment: The style attribute in the HTML tag itself has the highest priority.
Could be a quick fix, if you have two CSS classes with multiple statements and want to prioritize one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap itself doesn't prioritize these things, since it's only a 'framework', basically just a predefined CSS code. Confusion in your example stems from the fact that the Bootstrap defines 'pull-left' after it defines 'pull-right' in its files. If you'll open the source, you'll find:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Now, since they are both `!important` and pull-left is defined after pull-right *and* both these classes are applied to your element, naturally the one that was declared later dominates the rule of floating. If you will switch them, putting `.pull-right` after `.pull-left`, you will have both elements float to the right.

Also, it's worth to mention that there is a *specificity* prioritizing as well. Roughly speaking the class that was defined more precisely will override one that was defined more abstract.

Relevant articles worth reading:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/